# CSS all classes starts with and ignore some child class

Tags: html, css

I have a nested HTML element structure where I need to apply css styles for some condition.

1. Apply styles to class starts with "a-" in the `.a-comp` element
2. Ignore styles to `.a-col` class and its child elements which have "a-*" class

The code below works for the above scenario. But it doesn't work for other child elements which have "a-*" class.

How can I achieve that?

```css
.a-comp :not(.a-col) [class^="a-"],
.a-comp :not(.a-col) [class*="a-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-comp">
  <div class="a-one">
    <div class="a-col">
      <div class="a-text">
        Text1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row">
    <div class="a-text">
      Text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7sjfoeLq/4/)

Comment: Which elements do you want to target and which do you want to exclude? Please share your HTML and clearly indicate which elements should be targeted in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the example, now I have added it from the jsfiddle

Comment: You should consider instead using multiple classes in your HTML to target the desired elements, rather than using such complicated selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector matches `.a-*` elements that have an `.a-comp` ancestor, with some intermediate element that is not `.a-col`. However, both of your examples match that selector.

The first one has `.a-one` as a descendant of `.a-comp` and ancestor of `a-text`. The second one has `.a-row` as a descendant of `.a-comp` and ancestor of `a-text`.

One solution might be to set the appropriate children of `.a-col` elements *not* to be red.

```css
.a-comp [class^="a-"] {
  color: red;
}

.a-comp .a-col [class^="a-"] {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-comp">
  <div class="a-row">
    <div class="a-two">
      <div class="a-text">
        In a ROW
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-one">
    <div class="a-col">
      <div class="a-text">
        In a COL
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row">
    <div class="a-text">
      In a ROW
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-one">
    <div class="a-something">
      <div class="a-text">
        In something else
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```